# TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string

Tags: python, csv, python-3.7

I am trying to read a `csv` file using `Python 3.7` `csv.reader` on `windows` using `jupyter notebook`;

```
class my_dialect(csv.Dialect):
    lineterminator = '\n'
    deliminter = ';'
    quotechar = '"'
    quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL

reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=my_dialect)
```

I got the following errors:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-ddd19e28755c> in <module>
      5     quoting = csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL
      6 
----> 7 reader = csv.reader(f, dialect=my_dialect)

TypeError: "delimiter" must be a 1-character string
```

I am wondering how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a potential typo there:
`deliminter = ';'`

should be "delimiter" to pick it up correctly.

Reference docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter